# BeautifulSoup Condicional Python, Web Scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scraping

Buen dia, Espero me puedan ayudar con este pequeño codigo, Estoy intentando condicionar BeautifulSoup para que cuando lea las palabras "Sub-Español", Me imprima "Error", y si no me lee las palabras "Sub-Español" me imprima lo que pide el else. Soy algo nuevo en esto y no se porque me da error diciendome que btnSig no esta definido. Les dejo el codigo. Tendria que darme "Error" porque tengo seleccionado un href que lleva la palabra "Sub-Español"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls = 'https://monoschinos.com/ver/yesterday-wo-utatte-episodio-1'
page = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
eq=soup.find_all('iframe', class_='embed-responsive-item')

btnSig = soup.find_all('a',class_='btnWeb')[0]
if (btnsig.get("href").split('/')[4] == "Sub-Español"):
    print("error")
else:
    print(btnSig.get("href").split('/')[4])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mismo que Enrique, seria mejor usar un:

```
if("sub-espanol" in btnSig.get("href").split('/')[4]):
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Me ha funcionado.

Comment: Hola George, aunque la idea detrás de tu solución es similar a la de Enrique, sería bueno que indicaras cómo es diferente y cómo funciona ésta. (la respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido ya que es básicamente código). Lee [answer] y visita el [tour] para más información. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que Python distingue las mayúsculas de las minúsculas, entonces por ejemplo `area, Area, AREA, aRea`, son 4 identificadores distintos. También comentar que, el último ejemplo, aRea no es recomendado, dado su poca legibilidad. Si observas tu codigo tienes `btnSig` y `btnsig`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls = 'https://monoschinos.com/ver/yesterday-wo-utatte-episodio-1'
page = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
eq=soup.find_all('iframe', class_='embed-responsive-item')

btnSig = soup.find_all('a',class_='btnWeb')[0]
if (btnSig.get("href").split('/')[4] == "Sub-Español"):
    print("error")
else:
    print(btnSig.get("href").split('/')[4]) 

yesterday-wo-utatte-sub-espanol
```

Comment: Comprendo, No me habia dado cuenta de ese pequeño detalle, Muchas Gracias!.